Auto sign out/refresh token based on token expiry
I am running into a problem. I am not using next-auth in my NEXTJS project but handling custom authentication setting access token and refresh token into cookies on signin. Now I want to implement a global solution for auto logout or call refresh token based on access token expiry.
I am calling this component in my layout.jsx so it can be accessed to all children. The problem is this get run when component mount once so if i refresh page no matter which route its gonna call it and its working but initially when user is not signin and user signin its not calling it again because we are just changing route and this code is not getting triggered. it will get triggered if I refresh.
Let me know if this is ideal approach if not any suggestions please?
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function IntervalComponent() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null); // Initialize state for the token
  const [expiryTimeout, setExpiryTimeout] = useState(null); // To store the timeout ID for token expiry

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to fetch the token from the API
    const fetchToken = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/gettoken");
        const data = await res.json();
        const fetchedToken = data.token;

        if (fetchedToken) {
          console.log("token found");
          setToken(fetchedToken); // Set the token in state
          scheduleTokenCheck(fetchedToken); // Schedule the token expiry check
        } else {
          setToken(null); // No token, user might be signed out
          clearTimeout(expiryTimeout); // Clear any existing expiry check
          console.log("No token found, user is not signed in.");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching token:", error);
      }
    };

    // Fetch the token initially when the component mounts
    fetchToken();

    // Cleanup: Clear any timeouts when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      if (expiryTimeout) clearTimeout(expiryTimeout);
    };
  }, []); // Run once on mount

  // Function to schedule a token expiry check
  const scheduleTokenCheck = (newToken) => {
    const expiryTime = getTokenExpiry(newToken);
    const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Current time in seconds
    const timeUntilExpiry = expiryTime - currentTime; // Time left in seconds

    console.log("Token will expire in:", timeUntilExpiry, "seconds");

    // Set a buffer time before the token expires (e.g., 2 minutes before expiration)
    const bufferTime = 120; // 2 minutes before expiration

    if (timeUntilExpiry > bufferTime) {
      // Set a timeout to check token expiry 2 minutes before it expires
      const timeout = setTimeout(
        () => {
          console.log("Token is near expiration...");
          handleTokenExpiry(); // Handle token expiry (e.g., sign out or refresh)
        },
        (timeUntilExpiry - bufferTime) * 1000
      ); // Convert to milliseconds

      setExpiryTimeout(timeout); // Save the timeout ID so we can clear it later if needed
    } else {
      // If the token is about to expire, handle it immediately
      console.log("Token is about to expire, handling immediately...");
      handleTokenExpiry();
    }
  };

  // Function to handle token expiry (e.g., auto sign out or refresh token)
  const handleTokenExpiry = async () => {
    console.log("Token expired or near expiry. Logging out...");
    await fetch("/api/signout", { method: "POST" }); // Call signout API
    setToken(null); // Clear the token from state
    clearTimeout(expiryTimeout); // Clear the expiry timeout
    window.location.reload(); // Optionally reload or redirect to login
  };

  // Function to decode the JWT and get the expiry time
  const getTokenExpiry = (token) => {
    const payload = JSON.parse(atob(token.split(".")[1])); // Decode the payload from JWT
    return payload.exp; // Return the expiry time (UNIX timestamp)
  };

  // Watch for changes to the token and re-schedule the expiry check
  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      scheduleTokenCheck(token); // Schedule check if a token exists
    } else {
      clearTimeout(expiryTimeout); // Clear any previous expiry check if there's no token
    }
  }, [token]); // Trigger when the token changes

  return null; // This component doesn't need to render anything
}

I tried using userouter to look for any route change but I get an error on npm run build
